# How do you match rows of data when pasting "uneven" data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have two sets of data with some overlap, and some data not being shared. I'd like to be able to paste the second set of data NEXT TO the first set in a way that they align, based on the two name columns. I dont know what this is called, and I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'll try to demonstrate with this spreadsheet in three tabs:

[link removed]

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry I hadnt realised. I've added the spreadsheet link.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to manually enter data into the "empty" rows where a listing from Dataset 1 has no match in Dataset 2? Or will those remain "blank"?

Comment: If there is no match for something in Dataset2, those fields should just remain empty (Dataset1 is always going to be the more complete set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

A2:

```
=sort(unique(FLATTEN(arrayformula({if(Example!A2:A="",,Example!A2:A&"~"&Example!B2:B);if(Example!E2:E="",,Example!E2:E&"~"&Example!F2:F)}))))
```

B2:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Example!A2:A&"~"&Example!B2:B,Example!A2:D},{2,3,4,5},0))))
```

F2:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Example!E2:E&"~"&Example!F2:F,Example!E2:H},{2,3,4,5},0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mike, I've had an extensive look at this and after some initial confusion I understand! This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!